# How to do both removing zeros from the end of decimal value and inserting comma between its numbers using one StringFormat in WPF?

Tags: wpf

I have a decimal data type for a price field,and i want to insert comma between its numbers and  remove zeros from the end of them using `StringFormat`.
The `StringFormat` for inserting Comma is:

```
StringFormat='{}{0:#,0}'
```

And The `StringFormat` for Removing zeros from the end of decimal value is:

```
StringFormat='{}{0:0.#####}'}"
```

Now i need to merge this two format but i don't know how?Any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure if I got your question right. But maybe this helps:

```
StringFormat='{}#,0.####'
```